# datastage scd stage is updating old records instead of inserting no match business keys

Tags: datastage, scd, surrogate-key

we have dim build with 1.8 million records and scd is updating the old records instead of inserting the record when business key is not found.

need immediate help as this is a production issue....

we had identity on the destination table and we are not using surrogate key for inserts but for updates we are using and this is causing a lot of troubles...

Answer (score 1):

This could be because correct keys are not specified in SCD stage.